# Making a Button Text Based on Variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, button

I am making an unfair dice roller and I have a button with this code:

```html
<button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll the Dice</button>
```

The button rolls the dice, but I want the site viewer to be able to change what this button says. I have no clue how to do this. Does it have to do with a variable in JavaScript?

**Main Question:** How do I make the person able to change the text with a form element?

Comment: What do you mean by "with a form element"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: A box where people can type what they want the text to be. (I am fairly new to programming so I may be wrong).

I haven't tried anything, I just did not know how to do this.

Comment: Please may you update your question with an example of what you're trying. Especially the JS you have used.

Comment: You want to create a button with the values people entered? Make it look dynamic?

Comment: I want to make a button with a specific value someone entered. So if they want the button to say "Roll" instead of "Roll Dice," they can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this way?

Below code is create `button` tag. Also I set `button` tag attribute `id` and `type`.

**HTML**

```
...
<div id="root">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var buttonText = 'Roll the Dice';
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = buttonText;
    button.setAttribute('id', 'roll-button');
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    document.getElementById('root').appendChild(button);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first time get the element from document and then change its text Content property to the variable text.

Comment: Are you able to give me some code to do that? (I am not a skilled programmer.)

Comment: let btn = document.getElementById(“roll-button”); btn.textContent = “text which you want”;

Answer (score 0):

How do I make the person able to change the text with a form element?

Assuming that this is a text input, you'd have to get the value from the input then change the text of the button.

An additional text input field with the id "text-field" is added for this demo.

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById("text-field").value; //gets text-field value
var button = document.getElementById("roll-button"); //gets the button element

button.innerHTML = textInput; //changes the value to what the text input is
```